# Firebase getIDToken and how to use it in an API call

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

I have an API call that grabs json, but requires token authentication. Token auth works great, but when I try and pass the token along to the API function, it's coming back nil. I believe it's because `Auth.auth().currentUser!.getIDToken(...)` hasn't actually completed yet. Relevant code below... How do I modify this to

```
class SessionData : ObservableObject {
    ...
    func token() -> String? {
        var result: String? = nil
        Auth.auth().currentUser!.getIDToken(completion: { (res, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print("*** TOKEN() ERROR: \(err!)")
            } else {
                print("*** TOKEN() SUCCESS: \(err!)")
                result = res!
            }
        })
       return result
    }
...
}

class FetchPosts: ObservableObject {
    @Published var posts = [Post]()
    
    func load(api: Bool, session: SessionData) {
        
        if api {
            let url = URL(string: MyAPI.getAddress(token: session.token()!))!
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
                do {
                    if let postsData = data {
                        // 3.
                        let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: postsData)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.posts = decodedData.result
                            if decodedData.error != nil {
                                print("ERROR: \(decodedData.error!)")
                                session.json_error(error: decodedData.error!)
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("No data. Connection error.")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            session.json_error(error: "Could not connect to server, please try again!")
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("* Error: \(error)")
                }
            }.resume()
            
        } else {
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "json")!
            let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            if let products = try? decoder.decode([Post].self, from: data) {
                self.posts = products
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how the .load function is called:

```
UserViewer(fetch: posts)
                    .transition(AnyTransition.slide)
                    .animation(.default)
                    .onAppear {
                    
                        withAnimation{
                            posts.load(api: true, session: session)
                        }
                    }
                    .environmentObject(session)
```

Comment: You’ll have to use what’s called a “callback function” since it completes asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `getIDToken` executes and returns asynchronously, you can't return directly from it. Instead, you'll need to use a callback function.

Here's a modification of your function:

```
func token(_ completion: @escaping (String?) -> ()) {
            guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
                //handle error
                return
            }
            user.getIDToken(completion: { (res, err) in
                if err != nil {
                    print("*** TOKEN() ERROR: \(err!)")
                    //handle error
                } else {
                    print("*** TOKEN() SUCCESS: \(err!)")
                    completion(res)
                }
            })
        }
```

Then, you can use it later on:

```
.onAppear {
  session.token { token in 
    guard let token = token else {
       //handle nil
       return 
    }
    withAnimation{
      posts.load(api: true, session: session, token: token)
    }
  }
}
```

Modify your `load` to take a `token` parameter:

```
func load(api: Bool, session: SessionData, token: String) {
        
        if api {
            guard let url = URL(string: MyAPI.getAddress(token: token)) else {
  //handle bad URL
  return
}
```

Also, as you can see I'm doing in my code samples, I would try to get out of the habit of using `!` to force unwrap optionals. If the optional is `nil` and you use `!`, your program will crash. Instead, familiarize yourself with `guard let` and `if let` and learn to handle optionals in a way that won't lead to a crash -- it's one of the great benefits of Swift.